# Pi with 2 sata ports

Tags: linux, raid

I am trying to build a small NAS with 2 disks in RAID-1. Is there a pi with 2 SATA ports?
The performance is not required to be stellar, but I'd still like it to be direct SATA communication. I'm planning to use a Linux NAS system so no requirement for hardware RAID controller.

Comment: Obviously you did no prior research. The Raspberry Pi models are not that many and all well described on [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/). Also a quick search on stack exchange will reveal that there are alternatives like OrangePi and such of which offer SATA but are not supported in any way.

Comment: *"I didn't say it had to be Raspberry brand"* -> Sorry, shopping recommendations are explicitly [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon There is nothing objectionable or immature about curtly pointing out the **obvious.**

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for making this a pleasant space for everyone to learn and feel welcome, and for deleting my comment. Really mature.

Comment: Learning is not by definition pleasant ;) Which is not to say it needs to be nasty, either, but implying kwasmich's comment is out-of-line leans way to far in the direction of kid gloves. Not every criticism to be qualified with, "Oh please don't take this the wrong way, I am simply trying to help you understand something...".  In this case, the something is that **we are not a search engine** and it is disrespectful of the real live people that are here to help others to treat that as such ("LMGTFY").

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon there's a history of this behavior here. I think it answers this meta topic. https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/why-is-it-that-the-raspberry-pi-stack-exchange-does-not-seem-that-active

Comment: @goldilocks I completely agree. However stackoverflow's revenue model is dependant on the network effect. If we chase people away by deriding them (instead of saying something completely acceptable like "please do more research before asking") we devalue our own network. I hate being the SJW here, but I take issue with angry downvoting

Comment: @bobstro Have you ever tried asking a question on a linux SO platform? The community is rancid!

Comment: The problem with these curt responses is that they do nothing to indicate that there might be other solutions to the poster's dilemma. Not everybody posting is a native english speaker, and not every english speaker has excellent written skills. Rather than responding with snide comments, perhaps take a moment to suggest alternatives that might accomplish the same means. It's clear the OP wants to find a solution for connecting 2 SATA drives to a RPi. Be helpful in other words, or don't bother if offended.

Answer (score 3):

Could you maybe use 2 USB to SATA cables?

[image: USB2SATA]

Comment: @kwasmich: I didn't say it had to be Raspberry brand, and I did my share of research few months ago, but it fell short because most models were either SATA-less or had 1 SATA port. I did a shortcut here, but I'm sure there would be more pi-nions :) interested in this combo.

Comment: @Quentin: thanks for the tip, I'm not sure how much difference is there between USB3 and SATA, latency wise. How would it perform for small files?

Comment: @steakoverflow If you don't ask you don't learn. But then again there are right ways to correct and wrong ways to correct a question that may be lacking. I looked and USB3 seems 1 Gbps slower than SATA ATA. Remember these are Pi's, they are built as teaching machines so performance is not a priority, which is evidenced by the fact that the Pi 3's USB ports are only 2.0 (5.5 Gbps slower).

Comment: @steakoverflow - Keep in mind, you're only going to get USB2 out of a RPi. You can use USB3 adapters, but only at USB2 speeds. There are other brands of boards that *do* include actual USB3 (e.g. rock64) that might be more suitable to what you're after. However, as of today, everything in the RPi-brand lineup uses USB2 exclusively. Interestingly, I've had better luck using USB3-SATA adapters like QB linked to here than USB2-SATA adapters.